Install PHP extensions from a web interface in Docker Image
I'm looking to make my life easier...
I think this might interest you...
I have a multiple container installation or structure behind a reverse proxy container...
The containers behind the reverse proxy are apache + php containers... which can host more than one project through vhost.
The problem I am facing is:

I would like to manage (install, remove, update) PHP extensions from a graphical web interface, similar to this:


Note: I haven't found anything to help me install CPanel inside PHP containers to manage extensions for each project's sites.

Save configuration (disable/enable extensions) per project: "site-enable" / VHost.

If you know of any web/graphic interface that helps me achieve this, tell me.
This would be the hypothetical structure that I am implementing:
Docker Network
│
└── Proxy Server Container: Manage Custom URL like https://test.dock 
    ├── MySql Server
    ├── PhpMyadmin
    ├── php 7.2
    ├── php 8.2
    ├── PhpMyadmin
    ├── Project 1 server: code repository (API Point to php 7.2)
    ├── Project 2 server: code repository (API Point to php 8.2)
    ├── Project 3 server: code repository (Laravel Project Point to php 7.2)
    └── Project 4 server: code repository (Synfony Project Point to php 8.2)

